# truncate_html helper inside mailer views with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using helpers inside mailer views and this it works fine:

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer

  helper :home
  helper :post
  .
  .
  .
end
```

However, I need to use [truncate_html](https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html) gem inside mailer views

How can I add this helper to mailer views?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `include TruncateHtmlHelper` and `helper :truncate_html_helper`

Comment: Error: `LoadError: Missing helper file helpers/truncate_html_helper.rb`. Thanks!

Comment: try without the `include TruncateHtmlHelper` but just helper :truncate_html_helper

Comment: I'm sorry but I got more errors with this code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
  include TruncateHtmlHelper
  helper_method :truncate_html
end
```